# Fix a CSV File's Format

Tags: python, csv

So I'm opening a csv file to parse, but certain lines in the csv are formatted incorrectly. The csv format is typically the following throughout:

```
'ipAddress','associatedTix''\n'
'ipAddress','associatedTix''\n'
'ipAddress','associatedTix''\n'
'ipAddress','associatedTix''\n'
'ipAddress','associatedTix''\n'
```

but at certain points in the csv (since there are more than one `associateTix` with an `ipaddress`) when there are more than 1 `associatedTix`, it gets formatted like the following:

```
'ipAddress','associatedTix''\n'
'ipAddress','associatedTix''\n'
'ipAddress','associatedTix''\n'
'associatedTix','associatedTix''\n'
'associatedTix''\n'
'ipAddress','associatedTix''\n'
'ipAddress','associatedTix''\n'
```

So what I was going to do to get the csv in the proper format was:

```
for line in inputCsvFile:
    chunks = line.split(",")
        if associatedTix in chunks[0]:
            #go through the following line's after that line until you find an ip address
            #go one line above the line with the ip address
            #push that column to the above row, and repeat until you get to the original line3 row with the ip address
```

The 3 commented lines are the one I'm having trouble coming up with syntax for, so any help determining that syntax would be greatly appreciated. Also, confirmation that my logic will get the csv into the correct format would be appreciated as well.

Comment: So there are four associated associatedTix with the ip in your example?

Comment: I doubt that's what your file looks like. Please just copy and paste a portion of it into your question with each line indented by 4 spaces. It's difficult to go backwards when reading a file, so to solve your problem it's necessary to be able to differentiate between ipaddresses and associcatedTixes, I can't tell if that's possible because you haven't shown us what the data really looks like.

Comment: @martineau, you could just store the text of the file in a variable and `enumerate` the lines in the csv file to find the previous line.
@pHorseSpec, I do not quite understand what you mean but it seems that you would end up with multiple duplicates of similar lines and the csv file would not be fixed. Could you provide an example of a before and after?

Comment: @Moon: Clearly looking back wouldn't be a problem if the whole thing was read into memory first. However doing that shouldn't be one's automatic reaction to solving such problems since the file in question might be huge. Regardless, there needs to be some way to distinguish between the two types of data contained in this one in order to do what the OP wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`csv` handles fields with newlines properly as long as they are quoted:

```
$ cat t.csv
136.107.169.150,
165.246.197.229,"ESCCB ID#: 90Z-009204,
ESCCB ID#: 90Z-003262,
ESCCB ID#: 90Z-003011                   ESCCB ID#: 90Z-001047"
155.89.77.11,
91.195.188.160,
154.176.191.130,
```

...

```
>>> with open('t.csv') as fp:
...   read = csv.reader(fp)
...   for line in read:
...     print line
... 
['136.107.169.150', '']
['165.246.197.229', 'ESCCB ID#: 90Z-009204,\nESCCB ID#: 90Z-003262,\nESCCB ID#: 90Z-003011                   ESCCB ID#: 90Z-001047']
['155.89.77.11', '']
['91.195.188.160', '']
['154.176.191.130', '']
```

So the problem you think you have, you actually don't. All you need to do is post-process the second field and then write it back out.

Answer (score 1):

As Ignacio has said, there isn't really a problem if you are using the `csv` module. If you don't want to use it, use this:

```
with open("inCSV.txt", "r") as f:
    text = f.read()
    # Buffer
    b = ""
    keep_reading = False
    for line in text.split("\n"):
        if "\"" in line:
            # A bunch of tixs are going to appear!
            if b == "":
                # There are more tixs to read
                b += line
                # More tixs to come
                keep_reading = True
            else:
                # This is the last tix to read
                b += line.replace(",", "")
                # Remove newlines, extra whitespace and commas
                b = b.translate(None, " ,\n\"")
                # Add nice looking whitespace
                b = b.replace("E", " E")
                b = b.replace(":", ": ")
                b = b.replace("I", " I")
                b = b.strip()
                # Add comma after IP address
                ip_index = b.find(" ")
                b = b.replace(b[:ip_index + 1], b[:ip_index] + ",")
                # No more tixs to read
                keep_reading = False

                print b
                # reset buffer
                b = ""
        elif keep_reading:
            b += line
        else:
            print line
```

The advantage to this is, as martineau has said, you do not need to store the whole file in memory.

If you use the `csv` module however, you would have to do a bit more manipulation:

```
import csv
with open("inCSV.txt", "r") as f:
    text = csv.reader(f)
    for line in text:
        # Get associated tix
        tix = line[1]
        # Remove newlines, extra whitespace and commas
        tix = tix.translate(None, " ,\n")
        # Add nice looking whitespace
        tix = tix.replace("E", " E")
        tix = tix.replace(":", ": ")
        tix = tix.strip()

        line[1] = tix
        print line
```

both will give you:

```
['248.53.88.234-24', '']
['61.15.168.199-24', '']
['181.140.27.200', '']
['192.128.254.150', '']
['8.160.137.156', 'ESCCB ID#: 90Z-007463']
['136.107.169.150', '']
['165.246.197.229', 'ESCCB ID#: 90Z-009204 ESCCB ID#: 90Z-003262 ESCCB ID#: 90Z-003011 ESCCB ID#: 90Z-001047']
['155.89.77.11', '']
['91.195.188.160', '']
['154.176.191.130', '']
['105.98.164.205', '']
['245.6.16.92', '']
['207.108.19.66', 'ESCCB ID#: 90Z-002345']
['84.71.75.211', 'ESCCB ID#: 90Z-008567 ESCCB ID#: 90Z-006765 ESCCB ID#: 90Z-009384ESCCB ID#: 90Z-001234ESCCB ID#: 90Z-007465']
['33.236.5.19', '']
['127.42.160.158', 'ESCCB ID#: 90Z-002939']
['94.34.104.184', '']
```